# How to fix NewTeams not starting on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams, teams

I have the new Teams installed on windows 10, and sometimes it is starting normally (when clicking on the icon in the bottom bar on the screen), and some times it does not start at all.
In the latter case I have to enter "Teams" in the search bar and open the old teams.

Is there a way I can debug and fix this myself?

When teams is not starting up there is no error message, no process related to teams seems to be created, there is no process related to teams to be found in the Task Manager. Just like I did not "do" anything ...

Answer (score -1):

The old Teams shouldn't have stayed in the Start menu.

I suggest to use [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/)
to eradicate and clean out *all* the installed versions of Teams,
then install again the latest Teams, which will be the only one
installed this time.

Comment: Why this downvote? Explanation please.